# Add values to parameter in url as one value and not an array - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method I would like to use for testing that just makes a GET request to a specific url. The parameter for the url is just one parameter with multiple values that can be passed seperated by commas.

an ideal request should have the url look like : 
`url + "/items?item_ids?=1,2,3,4"`

My method accepts multiple arguments:

`def method(*args)
   url = url + "/items?item_ids?=#{args}"
end`

The issue I am having is that it will input the args into the url as an array which does not work. Is there a good way to add the arguments to the url not as an array and only seperated by commas? There will be an unknown number of arguments passed into this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically using string interpolation on an array of arguments. You can easily change the array into a string of arguments separated by commas by doing

```
def method(*args)
  url = url + "/items?item_ids?=#{args.join(',')}"
end
```

Get me 99 slayer on Runescape bro ;)

Comment: Wow that was very simple and I was overthinking this. Thanks for the help. Will see what I can do for Runescape haha

Answer (score 0):

Going by the standard rails convention, and assuming `items` goes to ItemsController#index action, you can do

```
#/items?item_ids?=1,2,3,4
def index 
  item_id_list = params[:item_ids]
end
```

At this point, `item_id_list` will become a comma seperated string "1,2,3,4" and you can perform any string interpolation fuctions.

E.g if you want all the ids to an array, you can do

```
item_id_list.split(",") #=> [1,2,3,4] etc
```